# Fix font size by using kaobook.cls

Tags: kaobook

I'm not familiar with `kaobook` and its supporting files.

My code are follows:

```
\documentclass[
    fontsize=10pt, 
    twoside=true, 
    open=any, 
    chapterentrydots=true, 
    numbers=noenddot 
]{kaobook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\fontsize{8.5}{8.5}\selectfont
\lipsum[1-9]

\end{document}
```

In PDF, the font size was displayed as `8.21`,

[image]

how can I achieve the given font size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as always, tex points are pt (1/72.27 in), pdf/postscript points are bp (1/72 in)

the class has

```
\RequirePackage[scaled=.97,helvratio=.93,p,theoremfont]{newpxtext} % Serif palatino font
```

so you get the font at .97 the requested size.

a request for 8.5pt is therefore 8.5 * 72 / 72.27 * 0.97 = 8.214bp as shown by your pdf reader